# Jhipster Angular App in docker container, not running in production mode

Tags: angularjs, webpack, jhipster, production-environment

Jhipster created angular app have following files in webpack folder

1. webpack.dev.js
2. webpack.prod.js

After creation of docker file using following code snippet

```
....

COPY . .
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm run-script serve"]
```

It always pick up development mode and webpack.dev.js.

Is any other change required for angular app to run in production mode.

Script file is as below

```
"scripts": {
    "prettier:format": "prettier --write \"{,src/**/}*.{md,json,ts,css,scss,yml}\"",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.ts",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "ngc": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json",
    "cleanup": "rimraf target/classes/static/ target/classes/aot",
    "clean-www": "rimraf target/classes/static/app/{src,target/}",
    "start": "npm run webpack:dev",
    "start-tls": "npm run webpack:dev -- --env.tls",
    "serve": "npm run start",
    "build": "npm run webpack:prod",
    "test": "npm run lint && jest --coverage --logHeapUsage -w=2 --config src/test/javascript/jest.conf.js",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "webpack:dev": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --inline --hot --port=9060 --watch-content-base --env.stats=minimal",
    "webpack:dev-verbose": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --inline --hot --port=9060 --watch-content-base --profile --progress --env.stats=normal",
    "webpack:build:main": "npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --env.stats=minimal",
    "webpack:build": "npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:build:main",
    "webpack:prod:main": "npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile",
    "webpack:prod": "npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:prod:main && npm run clean-www",
    "webpack:test": "npm run test",
    "webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
  },
```

Comment: Why do you want to use webpack in production? It's not its purpose. You should  consider using a real web server to server your app bundle without all these node dependencies

Comment: Actually we are deploying the app in K8S .. hence need to create docker image / container out of it .. trying to understand how to run it in production mode in side docker container...

Comment: Well the simplest is to use the default mode which consists in an image that contains the backend and frontend as an executable jar. Why do you want to deploy frontend separately?

Comment: Thanks I did it as you said